# In Foundry Contour, How do I filter by multiple terms?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

### ***Background***

I'm working on one of the tutorial exercises "[Bootcamp, Day 1](https://foobar.palantirfoundry.com/workspace/module/view/latest/ri.workshop.main.module.15a0a193-04f4-4333-9f43-81cb35316abb)"

---

### ***The Problem***

Specifically, the problem says

> Filter this Flights path to only: Flights between Delta Airlines hubs
> (ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX)

I know in SQL I would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM flights 
WHERE origin IN ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX
AND dest IN ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX
```

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Contour. I know I shouldn't have to put a new filter in for each airport and origin/dest, right?

---

### ***Question***

***How do I filter by multiple terms in one line?***

---

### ***What I'm Looking for***

I'd like to do something like

`origin` is in `ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX`

AND

`dest` is in `ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX`

But there is only `is`

---

### ***What I've Tried***

`origin` is `ATL, JFK, LGA, BOS, DTW, MSP, SLC, SEA, LAX`

`origin` matches (x) `'ATL','JFK','LGA','BOS','DTW','MSP','SLC','SEA','LAX'`

I get no data in the resulting table for either attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be hitting some issue, like adding all fields as a single string, containing commas i.e.: `"ATL, JFK, ..."` instead of `"ATL"` `"JFK"`

I've tried it with the Foundry Training Resources and it works fine, check the screenshot bellow:

[image]